# Composing Spring test configuration instead of inheriting it?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-test

I am writing integration tests for a Spring web application. To setup the configuration I am using the following annotations on the integration test class.

```
// Super class
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootRestApplication.class)
@IntegrationTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractIT {

// Integration test
public class SampleResourceIT extends AbstractIT {
```

To reduce the duplication, these are defined in an abstract base test class which every integration test inherits.

I want to use composition to load the integration test instead of inheritance as it convolutes the inheritance hierarchy of my tests. I want to store all my test configuration in one configuration class without using inheritance. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootRestApplication.class)
@IntegrationTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use @Import?

Comment: No that did not work. First it complained about Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. When I added the @ContextConfiguration it further complains about java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration [ContextConfigurationAttributes@4493d195. I then added the TestConfig in the \@ContextConfiguration but it is still not able to wire the beans which I need.

Comment: Moreover the documentation of the \@Import mentions that it just imports classes with the @Configuration annotation. I want to setup all the aspects of the configuration from the TestConfig class.